# jQuery filter with item preselected

Tags: jquery, filter

I have some simple filtering which I like but I was trying to have one of the options **preselected** to begin with. "All" is currently the default selection but I was trying to get "Black" to be selected already. Couldn't get it right. Here's the working version; fiddle link too.

**Markup:**

```
<ul id="options">
  <li><a href="">All</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Black</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Green</a></li>
</ul>

<section id="types">
  <div class="black"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
a:link, a:visited, a:active {
color: #ccc;
outline: none;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul#options {
margin: 40px auto 30px;
width: 300px;
}

a:hover, ul#options li a.active {
color: #000;
}

ul#options li {
font-size: 25px;
margin-right: 25px;
display: inline;
}

div {
float: left;
height: 50px;
margin: 1px;
width: 50px;
}

.black {
background: #000;
}

.green {
background: green;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// The filtering functionality    
    $('ul#options a').click(function() {
        var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');
        var itemsLength = $('#types div:visible').length;
        $('#types div:visible').each(function(i) {
        $(this).fadeOut(30, function(){if(itemsLength == ++i){show(filterVal);}});
        });
        return false;
        });

    function show(filterVal){
        if(filterVal == 'all') {
        $('#types div').fadeIn(200);
        } else {
            $('#types div').each(function() {
            if($(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
            $(this).fadeIn(200);
            }
            });
        }
    }

// Adds/removes 'active' class to selected item
    $('ul#options a').first().addClass("active"); // Adds the 'active' class to the first anchor    
    $("ul#options a").click(function(){
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
         $(this).addClass("active");
      });

});
```

**FIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/nf2gh/3/

What should I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to invoke the click event for the anchor tag which contains black as its text, manually like,

```
$('a:contains("Black")').click();
```

or

```
$('a:contains("Black")').trigger('click');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nf2gh/6/)

Please read here to know more about [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) and [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: Ooh that works. However, I think the next answer is more future-proof? Very useful though; thank you!

Comment: @Ira But if you want to change the order of those elements in future, then you need to manually change that selector by changing its index.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got what you were asking well, but if yes, you could add:

```
$('ul#options a').eq(1).click();
```

Then, the black one will be default.

[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nf2gh/7/)

Comment: I think I like this option a bit better because it doesn't rely on the name of the filter item. Great. Thanks!